# ng-init a controller with factory object

Tags: angularjs

I have factory methods like

```
angular.module('mctAppServices', ['ngResource'])
    .factory('Users', function($resource) {
        return $resource('/MY/system/users');
    })
    .factory('Groups', function($resource) {
        return $resource('/MY/system/users');
    });
```

How can I initialize a controller for different methods like

```
<div ng-init="myObj: Users">
    <div ng-controller="GenrlCtrl">
     ...
    </div>
</div>
```

and then in my controller factory method I am trying something like this

```
function GenrlCtrl($scope) {
    //here $scope.myObj is undefined
}
```

Comment: As I know, you must implement `ng-init` directive under specific scope (controller). From your example it stays outside. `The only appropriate use of ngInit is for aliasing special properties of ngRepeat. Besides this case, you should use controllers rather than ngInit to initialize values on a scope.`

Answer (score 1):

Access to service has nothing to do with ng-init, which is rarely used.
AngularJS has [dependency injection](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di) mechanism. Declare service name in function signature, then you can access it.

In your case, controller can be written like this:

```
function GenrlCtrl($scope, Users, Groups) {
    $scope.factoryMethod = User.query();
}
```

while HTML can simplify to:

```
<div ng-controller="GenrlCtrl">
 ...
</div>
```

By the way, here's a [short video](https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-using-resource-for-data-models) showing how to use $resource.